# Laravel Eloquent - Soft deleting is not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have added `$table->softDeletes()` to my migration file and have added the `protected $softDelete = true;` to my model, and I do have the `deleted_at` in my table. But whenever I call `delete()`, the entire row is deleted. Here is how I am calling my delete:

```
Schedule::whereId($id)->whereClientId($client_id)->delete();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that should work. Are you using Laravel 4 or later? Make sure that the `protected $softDelete = true;` is in place. If you run `dd(new Schedule());`, you should be able to see `"softDelete":protected]=> bool(true)`.

Comment: Yes, it does `protected 'softDelete' => boolean true` but I swear to god it is being deleted! And I am using Laravel 4.2

Comment: You're certain it's being deleted from the database itself?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the db, and the row is fully removed.

Comment: please add `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());` after the query and share the result

Answer (score 5):

In case somebody bumps into this question. You can still use SoftDeletes in Laravel 5. Just use the softdeletes trait.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; //<--- use the softdelete traits

class YourModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes; //<--- use the softdelete traits

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at']; //<--- new field to be added in your table

    protected $fillable = [

    ];
}
```

You can view [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#soft-deleting) or [This great tutorial on how to softdelete](http://anytch.com/how-to-soft-delete-on-laravel-5/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're overriding `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::boot` for whatever reason, ensure you call `parent::boot` in the method so traits (like `SoftDeletes`) can be booted.